# How finalizable objects takes at least 2 garbage collection cycles before it can be reclaimed?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, finalize

I'm reading [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp01274/index.html) article and I can't really understand **how the finalizable objects (objects which override the `finalize` method) takes at least 2 GC cycles before it can be reclaimed**.

> It takes at least two garbage collection cycles (in the best case) before a finalizeable object can be reclaimed.

Can someone also explain in detail **how is it possible for a finalizable object to take more than one GC cycle for reclamation?**

My logical argument is that when we override finalize method, the runtime will have to register this object with the garbage-collector (so that GC can call `finalize` of this object, which makes me think that GC will have reference to all the finalizable objects). And for this, GC will have to keep a strong reference to the finalizable object. If that is the case then how this object became a candidate for reclamation by GC in the first place? I reach a contradiction by this theory.

PS: I understand that overriding `finalize` is not the recommended approach and this method is deprecated since Java 9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right in that the garbage collector needs a reference to finalizable objects. Of course, this particular reference must not be considered when deciding whether the object is still reachable before the finalization. This implies special knowledge about the nature of this reference to the garbage collector.

When the garbage collector determines that an object is eligible for finalization, the finalizer will run, which implies that the object becomes strongly reachable again, at least as long as the finalizer is executed. After its finalization, the object must become unreachable again and this must be detected, before the object’s memory can be reclaimed. That’s why it takes at least two garbage collection cycles.

In case of the widely used Hotspot/OpenJDK environment (and likely also in IBM’s JVM), this is implemented by creating an instance of a special, non-public subclass of [`Reference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Reference.html), a [`Finalizer`](https://www.zgrepcode.com/java/oracle/jdk-8u181/java/lang/ref/finalizer.java), right when an object, whose class has a non-trivial `finalize()` method, is created. Like with weak & soft references, these references are enqueued by the garbage collector when no strong reference to the referent exist, but they are not cleared, so the finalizer thread can read the object, making it strongly reachable again for the finalization. At this point, the `Finalizer` is cleared, but also not referenced anymore, so it would get collected like an ordinary object anyway, so by the next time the referent becomes unreachable, no special reference to it exists anymore.

For objects whose class has a “trivial finalizer”, i.e. the `finalize()` method inherited by `java.lang.Object` or an empty `finalize()` method, the JVM will take a short-cut and not create the `Finalizer` instance in the first place, so you could say, these objects, which make the majority of all objects, behave as if their finalizer did already run, right from the start.

Comment: thanks for this clear explanation. I understand now that why we require more than 1 GC cycle for objects that have non-trivial `finalize`. But I still don't understand why they require **at least two** cycles. Can you explain that also.

Comment: yes I understand that. But I can't figure out why it will take **at least two** and not **exactly two**. Basically I don't understand the case when it can take more than 2 GC cycles. Can you please also explain that.

Comment: Because there is no guaranty that a garbage collection cycle identifies a particular unreachable object. Any general statement has to be careful not to promise something that is not guaranteed. Practically, it might be possible that the second (and 3rd and 4th…) garbage collection cycle happens when the finalizer is still running, hence, the object is still reachable. In fact, the 2nd cycle may even happen while the object is still enqueued and the finalization has not even started yet. And garbage collectors supporting a max pause time may not identify all unreachable objects in one cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Though you got your answer (which is absolutely correct), I want to add a small-ish addendum here. In general, references are of two types : *strong* and *weak*. Weak References are `WeakReference/SoftReference/PhantomReference` and `Finalizer`(s).

When a certain GC cycle traverses the heap graph and sees one of these `weak references`, it treats it in a special way. When it first encounters a dead finalizer reference (let's consider this being the first GC cycle), it has to resurrect the instance. `finalize` is an instance method, and it needs an *actual* instance to be invoked. So a GC first saw that this Object is dead, only to revive it moments later, to be able to call `finalize` on it. Once it calls that method on it, it marks the fact that it has already been called; so when the *next* cycle happens, it can be actually be GC-ed.

It would be incorrect to call this the `second` GC.

For example `G1GC` does partial clean-up of the heap (young and mixed), so it might not even capture this reference in the *next* cycle. It might not fall under its radar, as simple as that.

Other GCs, like `Shenandoah`, have flags that control on which iteration to handle these special references (`ShenandoahRefProcFrequency`, 5 by default).

So indeed there is a need for `two` cycles, but they do not have to be subsequent.